# Recyclerview android studio "hiding"?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

so I have a recyclerview, and in my recyclerview I have items. If I delete all the visible items in my recyclerview, one still appears to be left that was essentially "hiding" what is the cause of this? I believe that it is an easy fix but what is it?

```
public class AdapterTags extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTags.ViewTags>{
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Search> ListSearch=new ArrayList<>();
public AdapterTags(Context context){
    mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public void setTagsList (ArrayList<Search> ListSearch){
    this.ListSearch=ListSearch;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,ListSearch.size());
}

@Override
public ViewTags onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tags, parent, false);
    ViewTags viewholder=new ViewTags(view);
    return viewholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewTags holder, int position) {
    final Search currentTags=ListSearch.get(position);
    holder.mSearchText.setText(currentTags.getMtitle());
    holder.mAnswerPointsSearch.setText(currentTags.getMkey());
    holder.mSearchId.setText(currentTags.getMid());
    holder.mCourseId.setText(currentTags.getCourseId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListSearch.size();
}

 class ViewTags extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView mSearchText;
    private TextView mAnswerPointsSearch;
    private TextView mSearchId;
    private TextView mCourseId;



    public ViewTags(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mSearchText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.SearchText);
        mAnswerPointsSearch=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.AnswerPointsSearch);
        mSearchId=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.SearchId);
        mCourseId=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.CourseTextView);
    }
```

calling activity

```
private void JsonRequestMethod() {
    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ANSWER, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            ListSearch = parseJSONResponseQuestion(response);
            mAdapterDashBoard.setTagsList(ListSearch);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println("it worked!!!");
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);

        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: What portion of the code would you like to see? I have a ton, I cannot post everything related to my recyclerview

Comment: of course where you delete your items and maybe your adapter

Comment: post your adapter and calling activity/frag.

Comment: where are you deleting items?!

Comment: "If I delete all the visible items in my recyclerview", where do you do that?

Comment: I should have rephrased the problem, the problem is that when I do a get to the server my recyclerview does not show all the items it leaves the last one out

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to pass your items via constructor, and not to call notifyItemRangeChanged() as soon as you setItems. You should also check if your items is null in your getItemCount method, because if it is, your app is gonna crash. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that I edited my question, do you still have those recommendations?

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you're trying to remove items. It seems to me that you're only adding something to your recycler view. Can you review your code?

Comment: I should have rephrased the problem, the problem is that when I do a get to the server my recyclerview does not show all the items it leaves the last one out

Comment: Updated my answer, go ahead and try it out. :)